# I am getting NOT FOUND error on page refresh of Angular app with base href

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have updated my index.html page with `<base href="/vittal/app/">` and it launches the app perfectly works fine but if I reload the app or refresh the page, I am getting NOT FOUND error.

I have used the following ways to resolve the issue

Tried Solution 1(Not worked): 
in app-routing.module.ts

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
......

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LoginModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window.location.pathname}],
  exports: [RouterModule]
}
```

Tried Solution 2(Not worked):
I have tried PathLocationStrategy and not a HashLocationStrateg, concept to added hash(#) in the URL but still not worked, I mean I could not able to load the app with hash as well

Comment: How about like this ? providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: "/vittal/app/"}],

Comment: Is this on your local environment or when you deploy to a server?

Comment: It is on local(through Apache) as well as on the deployment server

Comment: @VittalKamkar may be this will help you with the apache config  (works upto angular 7 not tested in angular 8 though) : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: @VittalKamkar also  if angular 8 then add `providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: "/vittal/app/"}], ` as  he specified or  you could add `--base /somefolder/` flag while building the app  using `ng build `